# Visa on old passport when leaving China

Tags: passports, china, visa-expiration

I'm from the UK, currently living in China with a valid Z Visa. Both my visa and passport expire in April 2017. I plan to take a quick break in America before I return home and I need to start booking flights etc asap. Problem is I will have to get a new passport before it expires as the US does not permit entry with a passport that's due to expire within six months of the date of departure from USA.

If I get a new passport now and keep my old passport, can I still provide this to the police if I have a random spot check between now and April or does the new passport void the visa?

Also, will airport security have any issues with me leaving the country with my visa being on my old passport?

Comment: No, a new passport would not cancel a visa. Carry both passports. They may have an interval for transferring your visa, but this would be something reasonable. Your visa remains good in all instances.

Comment: I have carried an expired passport with a ten year US visa in it for seven years and entered the USA countless times and noone bat an eye. I suspect this is generic and not US specific.